# undesired heading with \includepdf

Tags: pdfpages

I only want a header on the first page, but instead LaTeX produces a header on all pages. Is there a way to remove these?

code:

```
\includepdf[pages={1,2,3}, pagecommand=\section{Appendix A: The SF-36 Health Survey}]{SF36form.pdf}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something of a stab in the dark, but it seems to me that you could include the first page (with a heading) and then separately include the rest of the document (without a heading), like this:

```
\includepdf[pages={1}, pagecommand=\section{Appendix A: The SF-36 Health Survey}]{SF36form.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={2,3}]{SF36form.pdf}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only wish a line on the first page, please have a look into the `eso-pic` package. Just leave independently from the `\includepdf`-command a remark on the page via eso-pic. If you would like to have the included PDF in your table of contents, you'll have to look for addtotoc.

Sorry, I can't give a tested solution right now, so: Good Luck!